# Recommended way of handling desired parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I handle an action that needs to be done before another action in ActiveRecord like *destroy* but forcing someway to select this action specifically?

For example, in our team we have Facebook tokens in our FacebookToken model. When we delete a token, it should be also destroyed from facebook, so we can end up with something like:

```
if token.delete_from_facebook
  token.destroy
end
```

But this needs to know the code. For example, when someone new arrives to the team, it could write this:

```
token.destroy
```

Of course, we can use before/after actions, but the code writer doesn't always know that if we have a large codebase. Or maybe, if it's just testing something maybe it doesn't want to delete the token from Facebook.

I would like to have a way to force a named parameter without monkey patching ActiveRecord preferably so we can end up with something like this:

```
token.destroy(delete_from_facebook: true)
```

This way, the reader can know explicitly what it is doing.

I would like to know if this would be a good practice or not, and also a way of do this.

Comment: How about creating another method, so you don't need to monkey patch?

Comment: Sounds good, but it also require new team members to know that. I don't know if this problem has solution actually without monkey patching or the one that you propose

Comment: Well, even if you could do it without monkey patching, you will need to tell your team that they need to add a `delete_from_facebook: true` parameter. So i think it won't make much difference than creating a method `complete_destroy` (i am terrible at naming) and telling your team to use it.

Comment: I was thinking to use a required keyword argument (https://medium.com/@gbenussi/keywords-arguments-in-ruby-6f98194110b5) in the case of monkey patching. But yes, is a good idea to use a new convention to avoid monkey patching. But also I want to know if there is a Rails way of do this.

Comment: That is a good option, i found it cleaner. By the way, you won't need to monkeypatch ActiveRecord, you will only override `destroy` method in `Token` model. And that way you will have what you are looking for: `token.destroy(delete_from_facebook: true)`.

Comment: Cool.. Do you know if this will break something? (outside our code obviously). I think that this should work very good if we don't breat anything needed by rails

Comment: No, it won't; check the answer i just posted. With that method you will be able to use `destroy` as usual or with `delete_from_facebook: true` parameter, only for your `Token` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `destroy` method only on your `Token` model, for example:

```
class Token < ApplicationRecord
  # scopes, associations, other methods, etc.

  def destroy(delete_from_facebook: false)
    facebook_delete if delete_from_facebook

    super()
  end

  private
  def facebook_delete
    # code to delete `Token` from facebook.
  end
end
```

Now you can call either `token.destroy` which will delete the record as usual, or you can call `token.destroy(delete_from_facebook: true)` which will delete the record as usual **and** will execute `facebook_delete` method.

Comment: Looks good. My concern is if it will break something but I think that is ok because I was thinking in a required keyword argument instead of an optional one. Thanks!

Comment: @GiovanniBenussi If you use a required keyword you will get an error if the parameter is not provided, so the default behavior of `destroy` will no longer be available. So maybe thats a good thing for new code (it will require everyone to specify  that parameter) but it could break any current code that uses `token.destroy`.

Comment: I'm only concerned about breaking something that rails would do under the hood @Gerry, I'm assuming that this will be used on a new model so we will not break anything from our current code. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @GiovanniBenussi Great, then you will be fine, this won't break anything under the hood. If it works, you can accept the answer :)